# Exim 4.63 on CentOS: sending mail from server app through localhost - failed on authentication

Tags: centos, exim

I am trying to send mail from my java application simply connecting on localhost:25 with empty login and password (I have to state them due to API).

Mail sending is failed then with

```
2010-03-21 12:20:01 login authenticator failed for localhost [127.0.0.1]: 535 Incorrect authentication data
```

On the other hand, when I am sending mail with telnet by:

```
$ telnet localhost 25
ehlo ...
mail from:...
rcpt to:...
data:
...
```

it works perfectly.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using a bad username/password. You are not authenticating with telnet, that's why it works.

To test with a fixed username/password combination, you can add this authenticator (assuming you use PLAIN)

```
fixed_plain:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = PLAIN
  server_prompts = :
  server_condition = \
    ${if and {{eq{$auth2}{username}}{eq{$auth3}{mysecret}}}}
  server_set_id = $auth2
```

Change `username` and `mysecret` to your needs.

Here is the [relevant documentation.](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch34.html)

To accept from localhost w/o password, add a line like the following to the correct ACL:

```
accept host = localhost
```

Comment: But can I somehow setup no authentication when sending from localhost?

Comment: Yes, you can setup the correct ACL to accept from localhost w/o authentication. I have edited the answer.